# Launching AWS Instances for a short periods of time

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm in the need of AWS instances but only for short periods of time, for example 1 minute every 20 minutes. This means, launching an instance, doing some work for a couple minutes and then shutting down for 20 minutes.

Does AWS apply extra fees or limit accounts that follow this behavior?

Quote from AWS page : Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the time an instance is launched until it is terminated. Each partial instance-hour consumed will be billed as a full hour.

Does this mean that each 2 minute session will be billed as a full hour? I'm guessing no, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you run or start an instance you are charged for at least one hour of run time (more if you leave it running past 60 minutes, obviously).

You will be charged three times as much for starting and stopping an instance three times an hour instead of just leaving an instance running full time.

Here's an experiment I ran in 2010 demonstrating this billing quirk:

- [EBS Boot Instance Stop+Start Begins a New Hour of Charges on EC2](http://alestic.com/2010/10/ec2-stop-start)